# Do I need transit visa for Hong Kong airport

Tags: transit, hong-kong, bangladeshi-citizens

I'm a Bangladeshi citizen... I'm going to Nanjing bt there will be transit in Hong Kong airport about 2 hr...in terminal 1
Via cx 
Do I need transit visa for transition in Hong Kong?plz help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a visa to transit according to http://bd.china-embassy.org/eng/lsyw/zjbl/t1390377.htm